# Django signals not working properly

Tags: django, signals

I'm trying to setup a signal so that when a valid form is saved, a function is ran to carry out a related task.

My app structure is as follows;

```
- events
    - helpers
        - __init__.py
        - status.py
    - models
        - signals
            - __init__.py
            - event.py
        - __init__.py
        - event.py
        - status.py
    - views
        - __init__.py
        - event.py
```

I believe signals need to be imported as early as possible, before models, so at the top of `models/__init__.py` I've got `from .signals import *`.

```
# views/event.py
class AddEventView(CreateView):
    """
    View for adding an Event.
    """
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('events:all_events')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()

        signals.event_status.send(
            sender=None, request=self.request, event=self.object, status=None
        ) # Should the sender be self.object?

        return super(AddEventView, self).form_valid(form)

# signals/event.py
from django.dispatch import Signal
event_status = Signal(providing_args=["request", "event", "status"])

# helpers/status.py
from ..models import Status, StatusHistory
from ..models.signals import event_status


def create_status(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a status for a given event.
    """
    event = kwargs['event']
    status = kwargs['status']
    creator = User.objects.get(pk=event.creator)
    try:
        current_status = StatusHistory.objects.filter(
            event=event).order_by('timestamp')[0]
    except IndexError:
        # Not sure what we're doing here yet.
        pass
    if not status:
        status = Status.objects.get(description=_("Submitted"))

    statushistory = StatusHistory.create(
        event=event,
        event_status=status,
        user=creator
    )
    statushistory.save()

event_status.connect(create_status)
```

I'm running the debug server in Pycharm with a break point in the `create_status()` function & it's never getting hit.

Have I implemented this wrong?

Comment: I guess you're aware they should be `__init__.py` and not `init.py` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think maybe you just need to import your `helpers/status.py` eg in `models/__init__.py`

otherwise your `event_status` signal gets defined ok but the signal handler `create_status` never gets connected by Django

if you only have one handler for that signal it might make sense to put it in the same module as the signal definition

Comment: Yeah I was considering moving it & importing the helper to the signal. I'll give that a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I've used signals in some of my projects and I allways import the signals in the `__init__.py` of my Django APP (Same folder as settings.py, views.py, urls.py...)

**__init__.py**:

```
import signals
```

**signals.py:**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete 
from django.dispatch import receiver
from my_project.models import *


@receiver(post_save, sender=Modelname)  # Called after an object is saved
def create_modelname(sender, **kwargs):
    obj = kwargs['instance']  # I get the object being saved here
    # ... Here I do whatever I want

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Modelname)  # Called before an object is deleted
def delete_modelname(sender, **kwargs):
   obj = kwargs['instance']
   # ... Do whatever you need
```

**Remember this 2 imports:**

- `from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete`
- `from django.dispatch import receiver`

**Remember to import the signals**

- To import the signals you need to add `import signals` in your `__init__.py` of your project

Using this code, this functions are called automatically by Django when an object of the class **Modelname** is created or deleted.

The receiver for created object is called **after** the object is created, and the receiver for deleted object is called **before** the object is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that `receiver` decorator used while I've been looking at this & used the `pre_save` etc methods for cache signals in the past for very simple signals. Can you add your own kwargs to a Signal using that method?

Comment: I think so, you should check Django documentation, it seems you'll have to overwrite the save method

Comment: just creating a `signals.py` file is not enough, this doesn't get imported automatically by Django... it'll only work because you import the signals from that file somewhere else in your code that does get imported by Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver

Comment: @Anentropic I use signals in at least 6 projects, and none of them import signals anywhere. It's Django who manage the signals, and when object is created, go to signals.py. I'm not saying you cannot do it in a different way, I'm saying this way works, at least for Django 1.5 and Django 1.6

Comment: I am still skeptical that this can work without importing the `create_modelnamet` signal handler from somewhere else in your code. I couldn't find any mention in Django docs of a magic `signals.py` file. Instead they say you have to explicitly import your signals module https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

Comment: same for older versions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

Comment: Yes the `pre_save` signal is _sent_ by Django, but the only way your _signal handler_ can register itself and get called is if the module containing it gets imported at some point. What I'm saying is that Django does not auto-import your app's `signals.py`.

Comment: @Anentropic you're right, I was checking my files and found the import, it's on the `__init__.py` like the tuto says

Answer (score 1):

I found one case that `signal` is not working.

Here are cases that `signal`(pre_save, post_save) won't happen.

```
Model.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(key=value)
```

Bulk model functions won't happen signals.