# Django m2m_changed signal is never called

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I can't understand why my m2m_changed signal is not triggered.

Here is the code:

**models.py**

```
class Badge(TimeStampable, Expirable, Deactivable,
            SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy = HARD_DELETE

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                              blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    restaurants = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=2048)

    objects = SafeDeleteManager.from_queryset(BadgeQuerySet)()
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Badge

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Badge.restaurants.through)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    print("M2M has been changed!")
```

**apps.py** ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135149/2255491) advised to change this file)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BadgesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'badges'

    def ready(self):
        import badges.signals
```

When going to a shell:

- `m2m_changed.receivers` returns an empty list (it does not work, and the signal can never be received)

I found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463863/django-signal-m2m-changed-not-triggered) but did not found the answer in it.

Why m2m_changed signal does not work?

**EDIT**

When opening a shell and importing `badges.signals`, it works.
It means the problem is in apps.py:

```
In [1]: from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

In [2]: m2m_changed.receivers
Out[2]: []

In [3]: import badges.signals

In [4]: m2m_changed.receivers
Out[4]:
[((4551224720, 4520068792),
  <weakref at 0x10f4da5e8; to 'function' at 0x10f462d90 (check_uniqueness)>)]
```

Comment: Please do `from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed` and post (in your question) what this gives you: `m2m_changed.receivers` (if it isn't an empty list, in which case the signal was not connected).

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform It is an empty list!

Comment: Try adding `m2m_changed.connect(my_callback)` to the end of signals.py and check `m2m_changed.receivers` again. (Might have to remove the receiver decorator from your callback).

Comment: The list is still empty :(

Comment: Try importing `badges.signals` in your app's `__init__.py` as mentioned here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038181/9313033). (Either the init.py in the folder with settings.py or your app's main folder should work)

Comment: Seems it's not related to how signals are import because it works for another type of signal (see my updated question).

Comment: How are you trying to trigger `m2m_changed` in the shell?

Comment: @BenjaminHicks yes

Comment: No, I mean what code are you using to make the m2m trigger, i.e. like `badge_obj.restaurants.add(rest_obj)` or similar?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Comment: Out of curiosity which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin 1.11.13

Comment: Just giving my 2p's worth: have you tried `@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Badge.restaurants.through, weak=False)`?

Comment: can you show us your `__init__.py` in this django app?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I tried with `weak=False` but nothing changed.
@SardorbekImomaliev `__init__.py` is empty, but that's expected because I use `apps.py` to register the signal, as advised in documentation. (I already tried with the __init__ method and did not work)

Comment: When opening a shell and importing badges.signals, it works. It means the problem is in apps.py!! (question edited).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my mistake in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) of Django the documentation.
From the beggining, my apps configurations were never called!

Actually, to register an app correctly, I have two methods:

**method 1**

`INSTALLED_APPS = ['badges', ...]`

and declaring in `__init__.py`:  `default_app_config = 'badges.apps.BadgesConfig'`

**method 2**

`INSTALLED_APPS = ['badges.apps.BadgesConfig']`

**my mistake**

I was using the `INSTALLED_APPS = ['badges', ...]` without declaring anything in `__init__.py`

I think maybe Django could display a warning when it notices that `apps.py` is in a folder app but never used.